# Primary key по двум столбцам MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Здравствуйте. Предположим, есть таблица со столбцами `user_id` и `user_group`, остальные столбцы не важны. Один пользователь может входить в несколько групп, то есть, получается, что `user_id` не уникален. Очевидно, что в одну `user_group` может входить несколько пользователей, поэтому и `user_group` не уникален.

Но связка `user_id` и `user_group` - уникальна, поэтому возникает вопрос - можно ли сделать primary key по двум столбцам и вообще, нормально ли это? Как правильно организовать таблицу в таком случае?

Comment: Абсолютно нормально, связующие таблицы обычно так и делаются. просто объявляете `primary key(user_id, user_group)`

Comment: Можно по двум столбцам.

Comment: @Mike и тогда значения столбцов `user_id`/`user_group` могут повторяться, а уникальной будет считаться только пара?

Comment: @Nik Да, именно так